# Best way to select and traverse records in database

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2012

I have a class Tweets which has some corresponding records stored in the repository.  I'm trying to grab the 10 latest tweets in the repository for a specific user and then traverse through them to analyze the date.

This is what I have come up with so far except for I am running into a issue where its saying that tweets does not have a parameter-less constructor..  But I'm a little confused because I'm not trying to initialize anything just want to take some records and traverse through them.

```
IEnumerable<Tweets> tweets = repository.Tweets.Take(10).Where(t => t.TwitterName == user.ScreenName) as IEnumerable<Tweets>;

foreach (var item in tweets)  
{
    var date = item.Date;        
}
```

Am I on the right track?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are trying to initialize something, an `IEnumerable<Tweets>` instance.  What kind of constructor(s) does `Tweets` have?  Is the `Tweets` object you're building (well, building an enumerable of) the same as the one on the repository?  If there's no parameterless constructor then you may need to add a `Select` to the statement instead of the `as` operator so you can manually build the `Tweets` objects.  Or perhaps inside the repository itself.  How does that internally build the `Tweets` objects?

Comment: No the class is not static.  My constructor for Tweets looks like this public Tweets(Int64 Id, DateTime Created, String UserName) { this.Id = Id; this.Date = Created; this.TwitterName = UserName; }

Comment: @Trevor: this isn't specifically related to your question, but the code snippet you posted finds the 10 most recent tweets then finds if any of them are by a given user (instead of finding the 10 most recent tweets for a given user)! You'll want to swap your `.Take` and `.Where` clauses.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for catching that for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning tweets from repository, so each tweet in result should be constructed. That's why parameterless constructor is required.

Constructing entities and mapping database fields to properties of created objects is what ORM does for you. Btw, you can avoid entities construction, if you will return only dates from database.